# Unable to decode base64 while read the data from console C#

Tags: c#, encoding, utf-8, base64, decode

I'm facing the issue while converting the encode/decode the data with C#. I have hard-coded the certain base64(encoded) data and its successfully decoded the string. As like below,

```
string encodedText = "eyJDb25uX0dyb3VwX0lEIjozMywiVXNlckVtYWlsIjoiVGVzdHNlcnZpc2VA\nZ21haWwuY29tIiwiVXNlclBhc3N3b3JkIjoib1ZkTEREWUVfX3FuSnZFSE1W\ncnR5WU5ZZzJSTnNzUnpaWG5KaFJMcCIsIkJhc2VVUkwiOiJodHRwOi8vbG9j\nYWxob3N0OjMwMDAifQ==\n";
byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(encodedText);
string decodedString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
```

But, while reading the same value from the console, its failed to decode the data. For example,

```
string readLine = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine("Received Data :: " + readLine); // Exactly same data received here
byte[] encodedByte = Convert.FromBase64String(readLine); //Failed here?
string configData = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(encodedByte);
```

The second code failed with the below error message

```
Unhandled exception. System.FormatException: The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters.
   at System.Convert.FromBase64CharPtr(Char* inputPtr, Int32 inputLength)
   at System.Convert.FromBase64String(String s)
```

Note:

I have noticed that and removed all the \n from the given string. Now, its working fine. But, I'm not sure how to remove that \n programatically. I tried with the below codes, but it's does not working,

```
readLine = Regex.Replace(readLine, @"\t|\n|\r", String.Empty);
```

And also tried with,

```
readLine = readLine.Replace("\n", String.Empty);
```

It would be much appreciated if anyone help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the original re-written to illustrate extra characters:

```
string encodedText = 
    "eyJDb25uX0dyb3VwX0lEIjozMywiVXNlckVtYWlsIjoiVGVzdHNlcnZpc2VA"
+ "\nZ21haWwuY29tIiwiVXNlclBhc3N3b3JkIjoib1ZkTEREWUVfX3FuSnZFSE1W"
+ "\ncnR5WU5ZZzJSTnNzUnpaWG5KaFJMcCIsIkJhc2VVUkwiOiJodHRwOi8vbG9j"
+ "\nYWxob3N0OjMwMDAifQ=="
+ "\n";
```

The data that should be entered in the console is then:

`eyJDb25uX0dyb3VwX0lEIjozMywiVXNlckVtYWlsIjoiVGVzdHNlcnZpc2VAZ21haWwuY29tIiwiVXNlclBhc3N3b3JkIjoib1ZkTEREWUVfX3FuSnZFSE1WcnR5WU5ZZzJSTnNzUnpaWG5KaFJMcCIsIkJhc2VVUkwiOiJodHRwOi8vbG9jYWxob3N0OjMwMDAifQ==`

There is no encoding issue present with this data "when cleaned up", and it will be read correctly with `Console.ReadLine` if correctly entered. Try to pipe it in from a file if unable to paste such correctly.

The code from the literal works because of relaxed rules in that newline characters are ignored by `Convert.FromBase64String`. However, the translation (of "\n" to a literal newline) that occurs in a string literal does NOT occur when entered/read via the console.

Performing a translation of errant `\n` sequences that appear - read as *two characters* when typed in the console - would require code such as:

```
readLine = readLine.Replace("\\n", "");
// "\n".ToCharArray()  -> { 0x10 }
// "\\n".ToCharArray() -> { '\\', 'n' }
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem why it should not work, because when an string is input to the comand line '\n' would be escaped to '\\n'
Try this one:

```
readLine = readLine.Replace("\\n", "");
//or
readLine = Regex.Replace(readLine, @"\\t|\\n|\\r", String.Empty);
```

Comment: Thanks kanukiesel.